# MongoDB in a array of objects, show only objects which have a specified value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

MongoDB Schema that I have :

```
const userTaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
       {...}{..}{...}{..} //Multiple objs above here, I just need help with this userTasks

        userTasks: [
            // Array of tasks with date
            {
                task: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true,
                },
                date: {
                    type: Date,
                    default: Date.now,
                },
                done: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    default: false,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
```

The array of task looks like this : Current output

```
"userTasks": [
                    {
                        "done": true,
                        "_id": "6059c57339d5590b04cb0fec",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:47.881Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57739d5590b04cb0fed",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:51.558Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57839d5590b04cb0fee",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:52.528Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57939d5590b04cb0fef",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:53.497Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": true,
                        "_id": "6059c57a39d5590b04cb0ff0",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:54.323Z"
                    }
                ],
```

My desired output is the array which has only `done : false` values present, I do not want any `done : true`

I cannot change the schema, this is what I have to work with.

My desired Output :

```
"userTasks": [
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57739d5590b04cb0fed",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:51.558Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57839d5590b04cb0fee",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:52.528Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "done": false,
                        "_id": "6059c57939d5590b04cb0fef",
                        "task": "abc",
                        "date": "2021-03-23T10:39:53.497Z"
                    },
                    ],
```

I am unable to find any query to get the desired result. Please Help.

Comment: UserTask is actually around 150-500+ objects array and have a lot of true and false randomly.

Answer (score 2):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/GBF1aWVu0k7

Use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) in aggregation query

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/)

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$project": {
    a: 1,
    "userTasks": {
      $filter: {
        input: "$userTasks",
        as: "task",
        cond: { "$eq": [ "$$task.done", true] //this is working for me
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```